# Remove formatting

Tags: macros, formatting

I currently use latex `newcommand` to store (and format) "variables", like so:

```
\newcommand{\someVariable}{\emph{value}}
```

I do this for key words that I want to be formatted a certain way every time they appear, by typing `\someVariable{}`

Is there a way to remove the formatting from `\someVariable{}` for certain times that I do NOT want any special formatting, something like `\removeFormatting{\someVariable{}}`.

Of course I could just manually type the text `value`, but I prefer to keep it in a command so that I can change all occurrences of it easily.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a higher level definition:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\definevariable}{mmm}{%
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{s}{\IfBooleanTF{##1}{#3}{#2{#3}}}%
}

\definevariable{\someVariable}{\emph}{value}
\definevariable{\otherVariable}{\quotedtextbf}{x}

\newcommand{\quotedtextbf}[1]{``\textbf{#1}''}
```

Now calling `\someVariable` will print "value" applying `\emph`, while `\someVariable*` will print value without special formatting. Similarly, `\otherVariable` will print “**x**”, while `\otherVariable*` will print a simple x. Note how we can apply additional formatting such as quotes *and* boldface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\definevariable}{mmm}{%
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{s}{\IfBooleanTF{##1}{#3}{#2{#3}}}%
}

\definevariable{\someVariable}{\emph}{value}
\definevariable{\otherVariable}{\quotedtextbf}{x}

\newcommand{\quotedtextbf}[1]{``\textbf{#1}''}

\begin{document}
\someVariable{} \otherVariable{}

\someVariable* \otherVariable*

\end{document}
```

will print

> *value* “**x**”
>   value x

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want... the only thing is that it won't always be `\emph`, it could be anything really... `\textbf`, `\textsc`... sometimes I even add quotation marks to the text: `\newcommand{\someFunction}[1]{``\textsc{#1}''}`

Comment: @JoshuaSpence, how about pass three arguments `\NewDocumentCommand{\definevariable}{mmm}`, where `#2` is the unformatted version, and `#3` has the formatting (i.e. substitute `#3` in place of `\emph{#2}`). E.g `\definevariable{\someVariable}{value}{"\textsc{value}"}`

Comment: @JoshuaSpence See edited answer which is just dbaupp's idea.

Answer (score 9):

You can temporarily set the formatting command(s) to `\relax`. If you do this within a group, they will automatically be restored afterwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\goat{\emph{goat}}
\newcommand\noemph[1]{\bgroup\let\emph\relax#1\egroup}
\begin{document}
\goat
\noemph{\goat}
\goat
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define a "conditional emphasis" macro -- such as the macro `\emphvar` in the MWE below -- as follows:

- if it's given just one argument, set off in curly braces, it'll emphasize that argument; and
- if it's also given an optional argument, set off in square brackets with a value of "0" (zero), it will *not* emphasize its main argument.

With the code given in the MWE below, you could specify `\emphvar{Value}` to italicize the string "Value", whereas `\emphvar[0]{Value}` would selectively disable the emphasizing action of the macro. The `\emphvar` macro can thus also be used to affect the appearance of keywords in your document's preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\emphvar}[2][]{%    % macro has two args; first arg is optional
   \ifx#10{#2}\else\emph{#2}\fi}
\newcommand{\Keywordi}{\emphvar{FirstKeyword}}
\newcommand{\Keywordii}{\emphvar[0]{SecondKeyword}}
\begin{document}
\emphvar{Value}    % without optional arg.: emphasize macro's argument
\emphvar[0]{Value} % with intended optional arg., viz., "0": no emphasis
\emphvar[x]{Value} % with any other value for the optional arg., the macro's
                   % behavior is the same as if no optional argument were present

\Keywordi{} \Keywordii
\end{document}
```