# Latex dynamic macro definition

Tags: macros, xparse

I am trying to dynamically define variables. What I want to do is be able to define a person in the following way `\definePerson{MrTestKey}{Mr Test}{0400 000 000}{mr@test.com}` and then subsequently call `\nameMrTestKey` to return "Mr Test", `\phoneMrTestKey` to return "0400 000 000" and `\emailMrTestKey` to return "mr@test.com".

This is what I have tried so far... I use the `\defineVariable` macro so that I can call `\nameMrTestKey` to return a formatted (`\emph`) name and `\nameMrTestKey*` to return an unformatted name.

```
% To allow (un)formatted variables
% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51652/remove-formatting/
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\defineVariable{mmm}{%
    \NewDocumentCommand#1{s}{\IfBooleanTF{##1}{#3}{#2{#3}}}%
}

% \definePerson{key}{name}{phone}{email}
\newcommand\definePerson[4]{%
    \defineVariable\name#1{\emph}{#2}
    \defineVariable\phone#1{\emph}{#3}%
    \defineVariable\email#1{\emph}{#4}%
}
```

Comment: Why not use a key value syntax instead? `\definePerson[MrTest][name={Mr Test}, phone={...}, email={...}]`. For multiple arguments like this, IMHO a key value syntax is easier to remember than the order of the arguments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `\csname ... \endcsname` to create a control sequence with the desired name. So the following creates a macro named `\nameMrTestKey` with the value being `\emph{Mr Test}` if called with `\definePerson{MrTestKey}{Mr Test}...`

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname name#1\endcsname{\emph{#2}}
```

The `name` in the control sequence name is hard coded, and `MrTestKey` is the first parameter passed to `\definePerson`.

The `\expandafter` is required as the `\newcommand` needs to be dealt with after the `\csname`. See follow-up question: [How to know whether or not we need \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64020/how-to-know-whether-or-not-we-need-expandafter)

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\definePerson[4]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname name#1\endcsname{\emph{#2}}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname phone#1\endcsname{\emph{#3}}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname email#1\endcsname{\emph{#4}}
}

\begin{document}

\definePerson{MrTestKey}{Mr Test}{0400 000 000}{mr@test.com}

Name is \nameMrTestKey 
 
Phone is \phoneMrTestKey 

Email address is \emailMrTestKey 
\end{document}
```

---

Or expanding on your MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\defineVariable{mmmm}{%
    \global\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1#2\endcsname{s}{\IfBooleanTF{##1}{#4}{#3{#4}}}%
}


\newcommand\definePerson[4]{%
    \defineVariable{name}{#1}{\emph}{#2}
    \defineVariable{phone}{#1}{\emph}{#3}
    \defineVariable{email}{#1}{\emph}{#4}
}

\begin{document}

\definePerson{MrTestKey}{Mr Test}{0400 000 000}{mr@test.com}

Name is \nameMrTestKey\ or \nameMrTestKey*
 
Phone is \phoneMrTestKey\ or \phoneMrTestKey*

Email address is \emailMrTestKey\ or \emailMrTestKey*
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost perfect. Thanks. In order to use my `\defineVariable command`... I did the following.

    \newcommand\definePerson[4]{%
        \expandafter\defineVariable\csname name#1\endcsname{\person}{#2}
            \expandafter\defineVariable\csname phone#1\endcsname{\phone}{#3}
        \expandafter\defineVariable\csname email#1\endcsname{\email}{#4}
    }

Comment: @JoshuaSpence: See updated solution which incorporates adapts your `xparse` version.

Comment: Dynamically calling also makes use of \csname: \csname phone#1\endcsname.

Answer (score 7):

I would take a slightly different tack and have a much tighter user interface. As  [Bruno answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63624) in [\NewDocumentCommand with constructed csname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63568/), the general feeling of the team is to try to have well defined interface commands which are not 'dynamically' generated.

At the same time, I would store the data in a 'proper' structure rather than using a `\csname`-based array (there are performance implications to the latter approach due to hash table collisions). The information required can be stored in a series of property lists:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g__JS_name_prop
\prop_new:N \g__JS_telephone_prop
\prop_new:N \g__JS_email_prop
\NewDocumentCommand { \defineperson } { m m m m }
  {
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g__JS_name_prop {#1} {#2}
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g__JS_telephone_prop {#1} {#3}
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g__JS_email_prop {#1} {#4}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \getperson } { s m }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF #1
      { \emph }
      { \use:n }
      { \prop_item:Nn \g__JS_name_prop {#2} }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \gettelephone } { s m }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF #1
      { \emph }
      { \use:n }
      { \prop_item:Nn \g__JS_telephone_prop {#2} }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \getemail } { s m }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF #1
      { \emph }
      { \use:n }
      { \prop_item:Nn \g__JS_email_prop {#2} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\defineperson{MrTestKey}{Mr Test}{0400 000 000}{mr@test.com}
\begin{document}
\getperson*{MrTestKey} \getemail{MrTestKey}
\end{document}
```

(I have written code for a spreadsheet-like 'data tabe' variable type, but this is still experimental and probably not needed here.)

Comment: I have got a compiler error on Overleaf.com. Is there any specific setting that I need to set?

Comment: @SergeiZinovyev Over a decade of development! I've adjusted the naming of the functions and removed the now-unneeded loading of `xparse`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It works.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a single macro that defines the necessary commands to use a starred/unstarred version of name, phone and email:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\makeatletter
\let\var@format\relax% Default formatting
\NewDocumentCommand\definePerson{mmmm}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname name@#1\endcsname{\var@format{#2}}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname phone@#1\endcsname{\var@format{#3}}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname email@#1\endcsname{\var@format{#4}}%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname name#1\endcsname}{s}{%
    {\IfBooleanTF{##1}{\let\var@format\emph}{}\csname name@#1\endcsname}}%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname phone#1\endcsname}{s}{%
    {\IfBooleanTF{##1}{\let\var@format\emph}{}\csname phone@#1\endcsname}}%
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\expandafter{\csname email#1\endcsname}{s}{%
    {\IfBooleanTF{##1}{\let\var@format\emph}{}\csname email@#1\endcsname}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\definePerson{MrTestKey}{Mr Test}{1-234-567-8901}{mr@test.com}
\definePerson{MrsTestKey}{Mrs Test}{1-234-567-8901}{mrs@test.com}
\nameMrTestKey\ \phoneMrTestKey*\ \emailMrTestKey \par
\nameMrsTestKey*\ \phoneMrsTestKey\ \emailMrsTestKey*

\end{document}
```

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) is not really needed for this since the LaTeX `\@ifstar` can also be used to discern between starred variants.

Comment: Is it possible to make it understand the Cyrillic alphabet? `\definePerson{MrTestKey}{Моє Ім'я}{1-234-567-8901}{mr@test.com}` and `\nameMrTestKey` prints nothing for `name`.

Comment: @SergeiZinovyev: Did you add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to your preamble?

Comment: Thanks for the point. I added `\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}` and it works.