# How to know whether or not we need \expandafter?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, programming

The following is quoted from [Peter Grill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64019/9467) on question [LaTeX dynamic macro definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64015/9467).

> The `\expandafter` is requried as the `\newcommand` needs to be dealt
>   with after the `\csname`.

As a newbie in TeX programming, how to know whether or not I need `\expandafter`?

Comment: Thanks for reading my mind.. I was about to add a warning on my answer that this is the extent of my knowledge of expansion related issues so  perhaps a follow up question on that issue would be appropriate.  I am _still_ a newbie for expansion issues, which are the cause of most of my problems.

Comment: In a lot of situations *exactly one token* is needed. This is especially true for assignmens like `\def`, `\let`, `\newcommand`, but some other primitives also require this, for instance `\ifx` or `\show`. `\csname` is one token and would mercilessly be accepted by all the examples I gave as the token to be dealt with, which is almost never what is intended. So if the token to be given is a control sequence to be constructed with `\csname`, that construct has to be expanded with `\expandafter` before the primitive is seen.

Comment: Word count for `\expandafter` in my DocScape sources is 1227, at 36621 lines of code. I guess about 10% of those are not really needed, so you could say 1100 `\expandafter`s were needed to make DocScape (whatever that means ;-)

Comment: Interesting fact: this very question about how to use `\expandafter` to prepare arguments to other macros was the first thing I learned about basic TeX and also the reason I got the TeXbook to learn more.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Is your record still 63 consecutive `\expandafter`s? `:-)`

Comment: @MartinSchröder My personal record, yes, but that's from another age of my TeX programming ;-) DocScape has at most 7 in a row.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let's look at three examples from `latex.ltx` (the LaTeX kernel).

### `\@namedef`

```
\def\@namedef#1{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname}
```

This is entirely analogous to the `\expandafter\newcommand` that's the main object of the question. With `\@namedef{foo}` we get

```
\expandafter\def\csname foo\endcsname
```

and the control sequence `\foo` is built before `\def` comes into action: the expansion of `\csname` is the symbolic token whose name is what comes after it up to the matching `\endcsname` (with complete expansion, but analyzing this would take too far).

### `\loop`

```
\def\loop#1\repeat{\def\iterate{#1\relax\expandafter\iterate\fi}%
  \iterate \let\iterate\relax}
```

We use this in the form

```
\loop
  <code A>
\ifz<condition>
  <code B>
\repeat
```

where `\ifz` is one of the TeX conditionals and `<condition>` is the test that, if true, will make the loop continue. This becomes

```
\def\iterate{<code A>\ifz<condition><code B>\relax\expandafter\iterate\fi}
\iterate \let\iterate\relax
```

The first line is an assignment: it's executed and removed from the input token list, leaving

```
\iterate \let\iterate\relax
```

Now `\iterate` is expanded, so we get

```
<code A>\ifz<condition><code B>\relax\expandafter\iterate\fi
\let\iterate\relax
```

TeX expands/executes `<code A>` and then evaluates the conditional. If it's false, everything up to `\fi` is skipped, so what remains is

```
\fi\let\iterate\relax
```

The expansion of `\fi` is empty; the next assignment is executed, ending the loop. If it's true, then we obtain

```
<code B>\relax\expandafter\iterate\fi
\let\iterate\relax
```

Now `<code B>` is expanded/executed; `\relax` does nothing and we have the magic

```
\expandafter\iterate\fi
\let\iterate\relax
```

Here `\expandafter` expands `\fi`, which has empty expansion: so TeX finds

```
\iterate \let\iterate\relax
```

and restarts. If the `\expandafter` were omitted, the `\fi` tokens would accumulate, possibly filling the memory on long loops.

### `\@onlypreamble`

Several commands in the kernel are defined following the scheme

```
\def\@foo{...}
\@onlypreamble\@foo
```

which means that `\@foo` cannot be used past `\begin{document}`, where it would trigger the "Can be used only in the preamble" error. Let's see what `\@onlypreamble` does:

```
\def\@preamblecmds{}
\def\@onlypreamble#1{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\@preamblecmds\expandafter{%
       \@preamblecmds\do#1}}
```

First `\@preamblecmds` is initialized to empty. If we say

```
\@onlypreamble\@foo
```

we get

```
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\@preamblecmds\expandafter{\@preamblecmds\do\@foo}}
```

The first `\expandafter` expands the second, which expands the third; the last one, in turn, expands `\@preamblecmds`. If this was the first call of the macro `\@onlypreamble`, we'd get

```
\gdef\@preamblecmds{\do\@foo}
```

To make the problem more interesting, let's call now

```
\@onlypreamble\@bar
```

Again we get

```
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\@preamblecmds\expandafter{\@preamblecmds\do\@bar}}
```

but now the expansion of `\@preamblecmds` is `\do\@foo`: so finally we get

```
\gdef\@preamblecmds{\do\@foo\do\@bar}
```

and so on for every call of `\@preamblecmds`. When LaTeX works on `\begin{document}` it says

```
\gdef\do#1{\global\let #1\@notprerr}\@preamblecmds
```

The `\do` command is defined to make its argument equivalent to `\@notprerr` (that triggers the above mentioned error); then `\@preamblecmds` is expanded, so that

```
\do\@foo\do\@bar
```

(and many other tokens of the same type) will be executed.

In `\@onlypreamble` the `\expandafter` is needed to get the expansion of `\@preamblecmds` in the replacement text *before* redefining `\@preamblecmds`: doing

```
\gdef\@preamblecmds{\@preamblecmds\do\@foo}
```

would lead to a disaster, because the final replacement text of `\@preamblecmds` would be

```
\@preamblecmds\do\@foo\do\@bar
```

(with many other `\do...` combinations). And when the expansion of `\@preamblecmds` is performed, TeX would find `\@preamblecmds` and expand it, finding `\@preamblecmds` which it would expand, finding… ***Infinite loop.*** Oops!

### `\@ifundefined`

The LaTeX kernel provides `\@ifundefined` that checks whether the control sequence having as name its argument is defined or not (actually, undefined means either really undefined or equivalent to `\relax`).

```
\def\@ifundefined#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
```

The `\expandafter\@firstoftwo` and `\expandafter\@secondoftwo` are explained elsewhere on the site; here the `\expandafter` application is similar to the first one: the usage is `\@ifundefined{foo}{true}{false}` and the control sequence token `\foo` is built before `\ifx` comes into action.

What I want to underline here is that generally using `\expandafter\ifx` is *wrong*: for instance, after

```
\def\foo{foo}
```

the test

```
\expandafter\ifx\foo\foo
```

would return ***false***. So don't use `\expandafter` unless you *know* it's necessary.

Comment: In my understanding always using `\expandafter` in doubt cases is safe. If misuse of `\expandafter` is harmful, could you provide one example of it?

Comment: @HiggsBoson Using `\expandafter` when not necessary is not  recommended; you're losing control on what gets expanded and when.

Answer (score 28):

The short answer to this is that you need `\expandafter` whenever you need something expanded before the previous token (helpful, I know!).  In Peter's example, the code was

```
\expandafter\newcommand \csname name#1\endcsname{\emph{#2}}
```

(where `#1` and `#2` were arguments to some surrounding macro).  The reason you want `\expandafter` here is because the entire `\csname` construction is not *itself* a control sequence, and yet `\newcommand` expects the first thing after it to be a control sequence that will name the new command.  Without `\expandafter`, it will grab `\csname` itself as the name of the new command, and then it will error out because it is not actually undefined.

The philosophy here is that the `\csname` is "preparation" for using `\newcommand`, and the `\newcommand` itself cannot be expanded meaningfully until the following input has been suitably prepared.  The purpose of `\expandafter` is to reserve it while acting on some subsequent directive to transform the actual input into the desired one.

Answer (score 23):

Not to compete with @egreg's answer but to answer your comment on when *not* to use `\expandafter`.

consider

```
 \def\foo{hello}
```

which defines `\foo` to be hello. So that is safe and good.

```
\expandafter\def\foo{hello}
```

may not be wrong (but it may be, and often is).

If it's the common case that `\foo` is not yet defined then you will get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1   \expandafter\def\foo
                          {hello}
```

As the expandafter tries to expand `\foo` before the definition.

If on the other hand `\foo` already had the definition `\def\foo{world}` then

```
\expandafter\def\foo{hello}
```

would give the error

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
<to be read again> 
                   w
\foo ->w
        orld
l.3   \expandafter\def\foo
                          {hello}
```

as it is equivalent to `\def world{hello}`

and finally if `\foo` already was defined by `\def\foo{\bar}` then you would get no error but it would define `\bar` not  `\foo` which is good if that's what is intended, but may not be what is intended if you just add `\expandafter` "for luck".

```
\def\foo{\bar}

\expandafter\def\foo{hello}

\show\foo
\show\bar
```

produces

```
> \foo=macro:
->\bar .
l.5 \show\foo

? 
> \bar=macro:
->hello.
l.6 \show\bar
```