# Nested \newcommand for creating maps

Tags: macros

I want to create a simple map using `\newcommand`. My `\NewMapItem` command defines another command which returns item's value. `\MapItem` simply replaces to that command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\NewMapItem}[2]{\newcommand{\Map@#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\MapItem}[1]{\Map@#1}
\begin{document}
    \NewMapItem{Canberk}{Qwerty}
    \MapItem{Canberk}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't works. Output is:

```
line 5: Missing number, treated as zero. \NewMapItem{Canberk}{Qwerty}
line 5: You already have nine parameters. \NewMapItem{Canberk}{Qwerty}
```

Could you explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Latex dynamic macro definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64015/latex-dynamic-macro-definition) for the `\NewMapItem` problem and also [How to know whether or not we need \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64020/how-to-know-whether-or-not-we-need-expandafter) for a discussion about the matter.

```
\newcommand{\NewMapItem}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname Map@#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\MapItem}[1]{\csname Map@#1\endcsname}
```

You can't form a token in that way unless you use `\csname`.

---

A different solution with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% allocate a global property list
\prop_new:N \g_jnbrq_maps_prop

% the user level command for adding properties
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewMapItem}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_jnbrq_maps_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }
% the user level command for retrieving a property
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\MapItem}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_jnbrq_maps_prop { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\NewMapItem{Canberk}{Qwerty}

\MapItem{Canberk}

\end{document}
```

It's possible to check whether the property already exists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% allocate a global property list
\prop_new:N \g_jnbrq_maps_prop
% an error message for duplicate property
\msg_new:nnnn { jnbrq/maps } { duplicate-property }
 {
  Already~existing~property~#1
 }
 {
  Property~#1~is~already~defined,~I'm~ignoring~
  this~redefinition
 }

% the user level command for adding properties
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewMapItem}{mm}
 {
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_jnbrq_maps_prop { #1 }
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { jnbrq/maps } { duplicate-property } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_jnbrq_maps_prop { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
% the user level command for retrieving a property
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\MapItem}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_jnbrq_maps_prop { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\NewMapItem{Canberk}{Qwerty}
\NewMapItem{Canberk}{QQQ}

\MapItem{Canberk}
\end{document}
```

This will raise an error

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! jnbrq/maps error: "duplicate-property"
! 
! Already existing property Canberk
! 
! See the jnbrq/maps documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.37 \NewMapItem{Canberk}{QQQ}

? h
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| Property Canberk is already defined, I'm ignoring this redefinition
|...............................................
```

which would be more easily understood instead of the standard error issued by `\newcommand`.

Comment: Why `\newcommand` when we have `\def`? The vicinity of `\newcommand` and `\csname/\endcsname` seems to me very non-standard:).

Comment: @wipet Because `\newcommand` checks for duplicate definitions, while `\def` doesn't.

Comment: But the `\csname Map@soemthing\endcsname` cannot be duplicate. If this is not true then you have chosen bad prefix `Map@`. And when user type `\NewMapItem{the same as before}` then it is clear that user needs to re-define it.

Comment: @wipet I don't think so, judging from the original code.