# Include institution in citation

Tags: bibtex

Currently, when I use `\cite{sak2017neuralaligner}`, it shows `[Sak et al., 2017]`.

However, I want to add the institution (affiliation, organization, company, working group, research institute; if applicable, but almost always, it is), such that it shows sth like `[Sak et al., Google, 2017]`.

How can I achieve that?

Currently I use `beamer`, and bibtex, and this at the end:

```latex
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{../thesis}
```

I assume I have to edit the bib style somehow? And then also include such information in my bib file. I might use the `institution` field for that.

(Probably related: At some earlier point, in my thesis itself, I wanted to include links in my citations. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579660/extend-cite-to-contain-external-link). I assume I need to perform similar steps here?)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed it. I copied the `apalike.bst` to `apalike-institution.bst` in the directory of my tex file. I made the following changes in the bst file:

```
commit 9deacf1f32ee98bdd0de28a2eeb7f027dc1bcdac (HEAD -> master)
Author: Albert Zeyer <albzey@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 1 00:20:32 2022 +0200

    bibtex bst, add institution logic

diff --git a/slides/apalike-institution.bst b/slides/apalike-institution.bst
index 15df7f7..074d1cd 100644
--- a/slides/apalike-institution.bst
+++ b/slides/apalike-institution.bst
@@ -40,6 +40,9 @@
 %    8-dec-10  (OP)  Still version 0.99a, as the code itself was unchanged;
 %                    this release clarified the license.
 
+% https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base/btxhak.pdf
+% Zeyer, add instititution handling
+
 ENTRY
   { address
     author
@@ -240,6 +243,10 @@ FUNCTION {format.authors}
     { "" }
     { author format.names }
   if$
+  institution empty$
+    {}
+    { " {\color{cyan}(" * institution * ")}" * }
+  if$
 }
 
 FUNCTION {format.key}                   % this function is just for apalike
@@ -865,6 +872,10 @@ FUNCTION {author.key.label}
     }
     { author format.lab.names }
   if$
+  institution empty$
+    {}
+    { ", {\color{cyan}" * institution * "}" * }
+  if$
 }
 
 FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
@@ -880,6 +891,10 @@ FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
     }
     { author format.lab.names }
   if$
+  institution empty$
+    {}
+    { ", {\color{cyan}" * institution * "}" * }
+  if$
 }
 
 FUNCTION {editor.key.label}
```

And in the end of the tex file:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike-institution}
\bibliography{../thesis}
```