# Latex dynamically named macro doesn't work

Tags: macros

In this MWE, `\Nba` is not created.
How to have it ?

**Edit**
Remplacing `\newcommand` by `\gdef` makes `\Nba` exist but gives fantaisist value ? Any idea ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xstring}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\Range}[2]{%
    \xdef\NbMin{#1}%
    \xdef\NbMax{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\Numbers}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {#1} {%
    %
    \StrGobbleLeft{\i}{1}[\Decimal]
    \StrLeft{\i}{1}[\Letter]
    %
    \IfStrEq{\Decimal}{}{%
    % integer in the range
    \pgfmathparse{int(\NbMin+random()*(\NbMax-\NbMin))}%
    }{%
    % décimal in the range
    \pgfmathparse{%
    round((\NbMin+random()*(\NbMax-\NbMin))*10^\Decimal)/10^\Decimal}%
    } % \pgfmathprintnumber -- problème d'arrondi
    \Letter\ -- \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname Nb\Letter\endcsname{%
                            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\Range{-10}{10}
\Numbers{a1,b,c3}

% \Nba

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\Nba` isn't known in the loop already

Comment: My question is how to create dynamically `\Nba`, the loop has to create it.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But even at the end of the current loop state, the `\Nba` or `\Nbb` etc. macros aren't defined already, so it's hopeless to expect, they would be visible outside

Comment: Why ? I use the methode seen in the answer here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64015/latex-dynamic-macro-definition. If it's not relevant how to do that ?

Comment: Just for fun: try to call `\Nba` inside the loop, after the `\newcommand` stuff.

Comment: I had to replace `\newcommand` by `\gdef`. `\Nba` exists but gives fantaisist value ?

Comment: You could use `\csgdef{Nb\Letter}{...}` from `etoolbox`

Comment: `\Nba` exists but all the created macros give the same fantaisist number.

Comment: I think that the `\foreach` loop is not healthy here and that `\Letter` is not correctly expanded, but I can't show it right now

Comment: I agree. Foreach is nested and I always have problems with global and expantion. I have to resolve the problem differently.

Comment: @Tarass It would be nice to know what's the expected result and what's the syntax you're using. I'm pretty sure this can be coded more easily.

Comment: In any case, I get errors from your example: `! Use of \pgfmathprintnumber@OPT doesn't match its definition.`

Comment: you give no indication of what this code is supposed to do, how can anyone change it? The only thing we know is that it generates errors.

Comment: @egreg and @David Carlisle I'm sorry but I haven't any errors except `\Nba` doesn't exists. I thought comments in the code were clear enougth. I'll do better next time. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wild guess: you want that `\Numbers{c3}` defines a macro `\Nbc` that stores a random number in the specified range, with three decimal digits, an integer if no number is specified.

Here's an `expl3` implementation that relies on `pdflatex` for generating random numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Range}{mm}
 {
  \int_gset:Nn \g_tarass_nb_min_int { #1 }
  \int_gset:Nn \g_tarass_nb_max_int { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\Numbers}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:on { #1 }
   {
    \tarass_process_numbers:n { ##1 }
   }
 }

\int_new:N \g_tarass_nb_min_int
\int_new:N \g_tarass_nb_max_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tarass_process_numbers:n #1
 {
  \tl_if_empty:xTF { \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
   {
    \tarass_process_item:nn { #1 } { 0 }
   }
   {
    \tarass_process_item:xx { \tl_head:n { #1 } } { \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tarass_process_item:nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_new:cpx { Nb#1 }
   {
    \fp_eval:n
     {
      round
       (
        \g_tarass_nb_min_int +
        \tarass_random:n { \g_tarass_nb_max_int - \g_tarass_nb_min_int }
        , #2
       )
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \tarass_random:n #1
 {
  \fp_eval:n
   {
    (
     ( \pdfuniformdeviate \c_ten_thousand )/\c_ten_thousand
    ) * (#1)
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tarass_process_item:nn { xx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_empty:nTF { x }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn { o }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\Range{-10}{10}
\Numbers{a1,b,c3}

$\Nba$ $\Nbb$ $\Nbc$

\end{document}
```

Change `\c_ten_thousand` into a bigger number, if you need higher precision.

[image]

Comment: `c3` means a decimal in the range with 3 decimal digits (max), your code seams to give a décimal one non null digit on the third place after the decimal point. I tried to correct this, I can't. I my example `c3` coud be `8.123` . `b` is an integer, could be `-10`.

Comment: @Tarass I'm just too weak in numeric math. If you have a good idea about getting a decimal number in the specified range, I'll be happy to try and implement it.

Comment: If I try `\xdef\List{a1,b,c3}`, then `\Numbers{\List}` gives `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \Nba `

Comment: @Tarass Of course. I can't read your mind, can I? Finally, I find this a ***very*** bad way to set things.

Comment: the formula is correct in my example : ` round((\NbMin+random()*(\NbMax-\NbMin))*10^\Decimal)/10^\Decimal}` but I mess to transpose it in your code.

Comment: Ok then never mind, dont' loose your time. I'll try a better approach. My general idea is to generate several random numbers in a specified range with a specified number of decimals. Secondary, give a pattern : `a+b-c` for example then remplace a,b,c by the calculate values and show the calcul and the students make the calcul, in parallel latex calculate the answer to correct the student answer. I have already made all the show part. In need the command to generate the questions and the answers. The pattern could be more complicated (not too) with fractions and some partial calculation.

Comment: Another more complicated pattern could be `a/b+c/[b*d]` for sum of two fractions. The denominator of the second in a multiple of the denominator of the first one. `[ ]` notation is for partial calculation before printing the question.

Comment: @Tarass I think I have fixed the RNG. The call `\Numbers{\List}` is also supported.

Comment: Doesn't work here : `! Undefined control sequence.
\Numbers #1->\clist_map_inline:on 
                                  {#1}{\tarass_process_numbers:n {##1}}
l.67 \Numbers{a1,b,c3}`

Comment: @Tarass Fixed; I wrongly assumed the variant existed.

Comment: Thank you very much, but as you said it is a very bad way, I took another one, remplacing directly the letters by their random values, in one way to display, in another one to calculate the result. I'll soon see some questions on that issue ;-) thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the new command as `Nb\Letter` is not the standard way, `\gdef` expects a `\name` and not `name\Letter`. So I defined `\Nba` as `\def\Nba{Nb\Letter}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xstring}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\def\Range#1#2{%
    \xdef\NbMin{#1}%
    \xdef\NbMax{#2}%
}     
\def\Numbers#1{%
    \foreach \i in {#1} {%
    \StrGobbleLeft{\i}{1}[\Decimal]
    \StrLeft{\i}{1}[\Letter]
    %
    \IfStrEq{\Decimal}{}{%
    % integer in the range
    \pgfmathparse{int(\NbMin+random()*(\NbMax-\NbMin))}%
    }{%
    % décimal in the range
    \def\Nba{Nb\Letter}
    \pgfmathparse{%
    round((\NbMin+random()*(\NbMax-\NbMin))*10^\Decimal)/10^\Decimal}%
    } % \pgfmathprintnumber -- problème d'arrondi
    \Letter\ -- \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}% 
    \Nba\ -- \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
    }
}    
\begin{document}
\Range{-10}{10}
\Numbers{a1,b1,c3}    
%\Nba    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If works for `\Nba` but the loop has to create `\Nbb` and `\Nbc`.

Comment: And in your example `\Nba` should be `-8.6` instead of `1.21*10^50`.

Comment: Are the updated numbers correct? and what should be Nba,Nbb,Nbc?

Comment: The loop calculate randomelly a value for each a, b, c : a1 mean a decimal with one décimal, b means integer, c2 means to décimal. This values are the value you see at the end of the loop. In your example a is -3.2, b -7 and c -2.18. \Nbx should store this values for ulterieur reuse.

Comment: @Tarass : `\Nba` is known only inside the loop. It prints normally inside the loop as you see. Also the argument b should be b0, b1, b3..